# How to make differents redirections after login Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, redirect

I was wondering how I can parameter different redirection after login.

In one case : 
I have a form that Anonymous User can complete it. 
I save my form without user yet but I put in session the id of the form. 
After I redirect to login/register and the session keep the id of the form
And to complete I need to attach the form with the user. 
But everytime I am redirecting to the account of the user...

So I imagine differents cases to redirect after login and some parameter the previous path.

And I can after do that i need in the good controller to finish to reccord in the database.

If someone have an idea. Thank you for your advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most safe implementation is to register to the `InteractiveLoginEvent`, by which you can do something after the user logged in successfully.

```
app.login_listener:
    class: AppBundle\EventListener\LoginListener
    arguments:
        - @session
    tags:
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.interactive_login, method: onLoginSuccess  }
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: kernel.response, method: onKernelResponse }
```

You can check the session during `onLoginSuccess` for your form, and return the proper redirect response in `onKernelResponse`.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass redirect url through form, [from docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login.html#control-the-redirect-url-from-inside-the-form):

```
{% if error %}
    <div>{{ error.message }}</div>
{% endif %}

<form action="{{ path('login_check') }}" method="post">
    <label for="username">Username:</label>
    <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />

    <label for="password">Password:</label>
    <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />

    <input type="hidden" name="_target_path" value="account" />

    <input type="submit" name="login" />
</form>
```